# How to enter in R the results of each for loop run in a new column in a new matrix

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R and I'm trying to solve a problem by piecing scripts together and have failed to come up with a solution for the following problem.

What I want to do is to run the for-loop in the following script 100 times and have each results side by side in new columns in a data frame/table/matrix, ideally keeping the 1 column constant and merge all new runs to it.

Here is a script that I'm running:

```
# Test data.
data <- data.frame(a=2, b=3, c=4)

# Sampling from first row of data.
row <- 1
N_samples <- 50

samples <- sample(1:ncol(data), N_samples, rep=TRUE, prob=data[row,])
site_sample=data[row,]
# Count the number of each entry and store in a list.
for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
site_sample[[i]] <- sum(samples==i)
}

# Unlist the data to get an array that represents the bootstrap row.
site_sample <- unlist(site_sample)
write.table(site_sample, file="test1.csv", sep = ",")
```

Thanks for your help.

I'm trying to get something that looks like this:

```
 a    9     15     21  ...(100 columns) 
 b    15    16     19  ...
 c    26    19     10  ...
```

Comment: On a side note, it seems you can replace the `for` loop by `res <- table(samples)` and to get the right names back `names(res) <- names(site_sample)`

Comment: Can you add data frame/table/matrix to demo the result you want to get?

Comment: I added a demo of the result I want to get. Thanks already for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for (I'm pretty sure the values I used for sampling aren't what you want), but the following code segment is able to put the data in the format you're looking for.

```
data <- data.frame(a=2, b=3, c=4)                # Test data

row       <- 1
N_samples <- 50

newDF <- data.frame(names(data), row.names = 1)  # Creates new, empty dataframe

for (i in 1:ncol(data)) {
  # Not sure if the next line is what you want, but it works as a good demo
  samples <- sample(1:ncol(data), N_samples, rep=TRUE, prob=data[row,])
  # Adds the count of the values generated above as the next col in the dataframe
  newDF   <- cbind(newDF, as.vector(table(samples)))
}

colnames(newDF) <- rep(" ", ncol(newDF))     # Removes dataframe's column names
```